# How to use WC_Order_Query class with custom order status

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders

There is a new order status I created: packed.

I want to get orders with order status "packed". This order status must have been created at least 2 days ago. However, I have a problem with time. date_modified is not working according to local time. Has anyone encountered this problem and has a solution?

```php
$two_days_ago           = date(strtotime('-2 day'), current_time('timestamp'));
$current_time           = current_time('timestamp');
$args = array(
  'limit'           => -1,
  'return'          => 'ids',
  'date_modified '  => $two_days_ago_tomorrow.'...'.current_time('timestamp'),
  'status'          => 'a-packed'
);
$query = new WC_Order_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wc_get_orders` and `WC_Order_Query` provide a standard way of retrieving orders that is safe to use and will not break due to database changes in future WooCommerce versions. You pass in an array of arguments defining the criteria for the search.

More information: [wc_get_orders and WC_Order_Query](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query)

---

Since you mention *"This order status must have been created at least 2 days ago"* in your question, it seems to me that the use of `date_created` is more suitable compared to `date_modified`

So you get:

```php
$days_delay = 2; // 48 hours
$one_day    = 24 * 60 * 60;
$today      = strtotime( date('Y-m-d') );

$orders = wc_get_orders( array(
    'status'       => array( 'your-custom-status' ),
    'orderby'      => 'date',
    'order'        => 'ASC',
    'date_created' => '<' . ( $today - ( $days_delay * $one_day ) ),
));

foreach ( $orders as $order ) {
    $order_id = $order->get_id();
    echo '<p>' . $order_id . '</p>';
}
```